# flutter future do not set data

Tags: flutter, future

I'm trying to set langauge from a Future call. I can see that future returns an object with data(value has languageCode property and it's data) but I cannot set that data to a String variable

```
 class Api {
  String language() {
  String langaugeCode;
  getLocale().then((value) => langaugeCode = value.languageCode);

  return langaugeCode;
 }

 
 Future<List<Product>> getProduct() async {
  var response = await http.get(BASE_URL + 'language?begins-with=' + language() , headers: headers());
 }

}
```

Comment: where are you using language()? add that code too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Future<String> language() async {  
  var local  = await getLocale()
  return local.languageCode;
}

 
 Future<List<Product>> getProduct() async {
  var lang = await language()
  var response = await http.get(BASE_URL + 'language?begins-with=' + lang , headers: headers());
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to set the value `getLocale()` returns to `languageCode` so it can be returned by `language()` you need to make `language()` async and `await` the result of `language()`:

```dart
 Future<String> language() async {
  String langaugeCode;

  final locale = await getLocale();

  langaugeCode = locale.languageCode;

  return langaugeCode;
 }
```

The issue with the code in the question is that you get the value but only within the scope of the function passed into `then()`. Additionally `language()` is synchronous so it doesn't wait for `getLocale()` or its `then()` callback to execute before returning. This means the languageCode isn't available by the time the function returns a value.

Using this approach you'll also need to make sure that you only use `language()` in `async` functions and `await` it's result to get the value: `await language()`.